# Having issues with Low Poly Texture Colours

Tags: texturing, color, vertex-colors

Blender Novice here.
I been getting into some basic low poly modelling for unity and have been working on applying a simple solid color texture to one of my trees.

The issue is that the colors seem to mix with adjacent colors in the texture even though the mesh is contained in the center of the color on the UV map.

I have been trying various methods but cant seem to fix it.

Any advice on how to deal with this?

EDIT: I dealt with it mostly by shrinking my meshes even more on the palette and then trying a better seam. Original seam was running along the top of the leaves now running along the bottom darker area and I no longer have the color leak.

[image: As you can see in the image, green is leaking into the trunk of the tree from the colour below it in the palette]

As you can see in the image, green is leaking into the trunk of the tree from the color below it in the palette. As well as on the leaves.

Comment: Did you try to use `nearest(closest?)` interpolation in the **image texture node**?

Comment: I was also gonna suggest what Hikariztw  mentioned. Also, is that not just [color bleeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_bleeding_(computer_graphics)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably the texture interpolation mode. The default is linear, which is not what you want for low-poly. You need to pick closest

[image: bee-closest]

If you want to make it look right in Blender pick closest in the material settings

[image: closest-setting]

To make it look right in Unity select the texture in Unity and pick Point (no filter)

[image]

Or you'll end up with something that looks blurry and colour-bleed like this \/
[image: bee-linear]

Answer (score 1):

you probably have too high the specularity of the material, what I'm showing you is an example in blender render, I'm not a render professional, my area is programming, but I've been studying for almost 4 years and today I work with shading language, and I'm still using BGE.

in conclusion you have to lower the specularity of the material so that it does not seem like it is going beyond the spaces of your color palette

1. I made my palette with 128 X 128 px squares
2. use unwrap view project, with the View Ortho 1
3. from the leaves of the trees select some faces from my unwrap and place them in another color to contrast

if you need to expand this answer, just say uqe more you want to know to include it in the answer

[image: Color palette]
[image: Lamp SUN]
[image: Lamp HEMI]
[image: Texture]
[image: Blender Render WIP]

Answer (score -1):

You need to "rip" islands in UV editor. Otherwise they are still connected and this is why you see Uv sliding. Rip islands in uv editor, position them on colors. Profit.

Comment: en que parte de blender has visto que usen rip, minimo sabes que significa el termino rip ??

Comment: Select poly island. Tear them.

Comment: tear them ? how ???